# PHP upload problems

Tags: php

Any ideas why this isn't working? I've used it many times before.
I have a folder called 'uploads' in the same directory

```
$target_path = "uploads/";
 $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['file']['name']); 

 if(! move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
  $error = 1;
 }
```

The file input form seems to be working, as when i echo out `$_POST['file'];` the file name is correct

Thanks

Comment: what's the exact problem? if the file isn't being moved, you should try to use an absolute $target_path (/.../.../uploads) instead of a relative one (uploads/). if upload is in the same dir as the php file you're working on,

    $target_path = basedir(\_\_FILE\_\_) . '/uploads/';

will work

Comment: move_uploaded_files is what throws the error, i tried using an absolute directory too, that didnt work?

Comment: Can you also post the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that:

- You have specified the encoding type `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `form`
- The folder `uploads` has write permissions, chmod to 755
- Try prefixing the path with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the permissions of the uploads folder?  For uploads it usually needs permissions of 777 (Sometimes written as rwxrwxrwx), however I would try 755 or 775 first as there are security implications of allow full write access to global users.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have write privileges set to your uploads folder.